# Row level caching with "Index as Table"

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, arbre

I am displaying a table with ActiveAdmin using the ["Index as Table"](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html) functionality:

```
index :pagination_total => false do

    if Ability.new(current_user).can? :manage, :metric
        selectable_column
    end

    column '' do |metric|
        links = link_to(metric.icon, admin_metric_path(metric), :title => metric.comment)
        links += link_to(metric.data_icon, admin_metric_path(metric)) unless metric.datum_ids.empty?
        links
    end

    column 'Status', :success, sortable: :success do |metric|
        metric.success == 1 ? status_tag('Success', :ok) : status_tag('FAILED', :error)
    end
    column 'When (UTC)', :createddttm
    column 'What', :metric_name
    column 'Area',    :logarea
    column 'Subarea', :subarea
    column 'Value',   :value
    column 'Machine', :machine_name, sortable: 'machinename.machinename'
    column 'Domain',  :domain_name, sortable: 'domain.domainname'
    column 'Product', :product_name, sortable: 'product.productname'
    column 'Version', :product_version, sortable: 'product.productversion'
    column 'Install Type', :install_type, sortable: 'product.productinstalltype'
    column 'Lang', :language
    column 'Duration', :duration
end
```

Given that the row data does not change, I would like to add row level caching of the **rendered html** with a long expiry time but I can't figure out how to hook into the row rendering code in [Arbre](https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre).

I am currently caching the entire page for 60 seconds but that is not optimal. My cache store is Dalli / memcached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**

Try this with the `cashed_rows` method:

```
# lib\active_admin\views\index_as_table.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class IndexAsTable < ActiveAdmin::Component

      def build(page_presenter, collection)

        table_options = {
            id: "index_table_#{active_admin_config.resource_name.plural}",
            sortable: true,
            class: "index_table index",
            i18n: active_admin_config.resource_class,
            paginator: page_presenter[:paginator] != false,
            row_class: page_presenter[:row_class]
        }

        table = table_for collection, table_options do |t|
          table_config_block = page_presenter.block || default_table
          instance_exec(t, &table_config_block)
        end

        #new code
        rows = []
        table.children.each {|row| rows << row.to_s}
        resource_class.cached_rows = rows 

        table
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

**UPDATE:**
This is a monkey patch. Create a new file in lib folder, then you can use the `rows` array.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class TableFor < Arbre::HTML::Table

      def build_table_body

        @tbody = tbody do
          # Build enough rows for our collection
          @collection.each do |elem|
            classes = [cycle('odd', 'even')]

            if @row_class
              classes << @row_class.call(elem)
            end

            tr(class: classes.flatten.join(' '), id: dom_id_for(elem))
          end
        end

        #new code: rows will contain the html string for each row
        rows = []
        @tbody.children.each {|row| rows << row.to_s} #you can also use: @tbody.to_s
        YourActiveRecordModel.cached_rows= rows

        @tbody 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class YourActiveRecordModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.cached_rows=(attr)
    @@rows = attr
  end

  def self.cached_rows
    @@rows
  end
end
```

---

Now you can get the html string: YourActiveRecordModel.cached_rows if you build the index table at least once.

**Old answer:**

I would make a new table that contains the string representation of the contained objects.
You can determine which record want to load (the original or the cached record):

```
  controller do
    def find_resource
      if params[:action] == 'index' #or something similar
         CachedRecords.find(params[:id])
      elsif params[:action] == 'edit'
         OriginalRecords.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#customizing-resource-retrieval

Comment: That won't get me a prerendered row. That just adds a larger storage requirement to my app, though CachedRecords would really just be a Rails.cache check.

Comment: Can you provide usage ? I'm not sure how to call this and /or get at rows array

Comment: This is not a method that you can call... this is a monkey patch that overrides the `build_table_body` method. You can pass the `rows` array to your Class with a block or a method (for example).

Comment: Can you provide an example using the rows[] array from an activeadmin index block please?

Comment: I don't think you can reach that variabe in the index block, because at that point the index table hasn't been build up yet. But outside the index block you can reach it via class method for example. I update my answer...

Comment: This only works for one model. If I use 'index as table' for multiple models, this wont work

Comment: I don't get it.. the @@rows variable will also contain the string representation of the associated records as html string, just like the rendered index table in ActiveAdmin. (or not?)

Comment: The issue is the hardcoding of the model name `YourActiveRecordModel.cached_rows= row ` .. this may work for one model / page in ActiveAdmin but not for two or more.